# When should I scrub my BTRFS volumes?

Tags: btrfs, scrub

Scrubbing a BTRFS volume seems to be an expensive operation. How often should I be running it on a moderately busy system? Dayly? Weekly? Monthly?

Answer (score 1):

[btrfs-scrub manpage](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-scrub) recommends to run it monthly:

> The user is supposed to run it manually or via a periodic system service. The recommended period is a month but could be less.

Also you should still be able to use the system when scrub is running and it can be stopped and resumed later so it's something you can safely run on background.

> The estimated device bandwidth utilization is about 80% on an idle filesystem. The IO priority class is by default idle so background scrub should not significantly interfere with normal filesystem operation.